# « Ce qui se passe » ou « ce qu'il se passe » ?

Tags: usage, orthographe, subordonnées, pronoms-impersonnels

**Contexte :** *je suis dans une salle, j'entends des cris dans le couloir. Je demande à mes voisins [ce qui se passe]/[ce qu'il se passe].*

Quelle est la bonne forme à employer ? J'ai toujours dit à l'oral *ce **qui** se passe*, mais à y réfléchir, le *qui* faisant référence à une personne, c'est plutôt incohérent. Des pistes sur ce sujet ?

Comment: Des éléments pour que tu rédiges [la réponse à ta question](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic2781-ce-qui-ou-ce-quil.html). C'est sérieux, j'ai vérifié dans Grevisse, et vu aussi des bêtises en ligne !

Comment: I just found to my surprise that Duolingo Stories insists on « Qu'est-ce qu'il s'est passé ? » I had never seen this « qu'il » variant before.

Comment: Bonjour, j'arrive très tardivement sur cette question, aux hasard de recherches sur internet, car ce qui m'intrigue depuis un certain temps, c'est ceci : depuis... je ne sais, 5? 10 ans? l'usage s'est soudain généralisé dans la presse d'écrire "ce qu'il s'est passé etc." plutôt que "ce qui s'est passé". J'ai eu l'impression qu'il y avait eu une sorte de mise en accord généralisé de la langue des médias écrits. Bien sûr, ce n'est qu'une impression : mais j'ai 60 ans, et cela fait 45 ans que je lis les journaux! Bien sûr que grammaticalement les deux conviennent à égalité, mais il est intéressan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pour [Langue-fr.net](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article242) et l'[Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#20_strong-em-ce-qui-reste-ou-ce-qu-il-reste-em-strong) avec « se passer » *ce qui* et *ce qu'il* se disent et sont admis tous les deux.

Grevisse est plus nuancé et dit que avec se passer on met généralement *qui*.

Je résume ci-dessous ce que j'ai lu dans Grevisse (deuxième édition, 1975).

L'*l* de *il* s'étant, dès le moyen français, amuï devant une initiale consonantique, il a été impossible généralement de discerner l'une de l'autre, dans la langue parlée, les valeurs syntaxiques de *qu'il* et de *qui*.

Avec les verbes susceptibles d'être construits impersonnellement, il y a parfois hésitation entre *qu'il* (construction impersonnelle) et *qui* (construction personnelle) ; dans la construction impersonnelle, *que* est tantôt complément d'un infinitif exprimé ou sous-entendu après lui.

Avec *falloir* verbe toujours impersonnel, on emploie obligatoirement *qu'il* (Grevisse signale que la construction avec *qui* est vulgaire, même si dans la langage familier *qu'il* se prononce souvent *qui*).

Avec *rester*, on emploie *qui* ou *qu'il* au choix.

> Ce qu'il restait de fromage d'Auvergne dans son assiette. (A Daudet)
>   Ce qui lui reste de sainteté (A. Maurois)

Avec *plaire*, strictement parlant, il y aurait lieu de distinguer :

- *choisis* ce *qu'il* te plaît signifie « choisis ce que tu voudras »
- *choisis ce qui te plaît* signifie « choisis ce qui te donne du plaisir »
  mais dans la pratique on ne tient guère compte de cette distinction.

> Nous avions le droit de lire ce qu'il nous plaisait (F. Mauriac)
>   Je dis ce qui me plaît (G. Duhamel)

Avec *advenir, arriver*, le choix entre *qu'il* et *qui* est assez libre, mais avec d'autres verbes : *convenir, importer, prendre, résulter, se passer*, on met généralement *qui*.

> Arrivera ce qu'il pourra. (G. Duhamel)
>   Qu'est-ce qu'il s'est passé ? (Le Monde)
>   Quoi qui arrivât dans sa vie (Montherlant)
>   Va voir ce qui se passe. (Racine)

Answer (score 3):

j'aurais tendance à pencher pour « *ce qui se passe* », car si on pose la question: « *qu'est-ce qui se passe* ? » la réponse est « *ce* ».

> *qui faisant référence à une personne, c'est plutôt incohérent*

Non, le *qui* ne fait pas référence à une personne, mais à une situation, une chose inconnue sur laquelle on s'interroge.

Au final, je n'ai pas de sources pour affirmer mon hypothèse, toutefois cela va dans le sens de la première réponse du [lien](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic2781-ce-qui-ou-ce-quil.html) donné par Laure et appuyé sur le *Grevisse*:

> *Personnellement, je préfère QUI, chaque fois que c’est possible.*

Comment: évidemment, on peut aussi poser la question « Que se passe-t-il ? », mais je pense que le « il » de cette question n'a pas le même sens que le « *il* » de « *ce qu'**il** se passe* »