# « Qui reste » ou « qu’il reste »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Qu’en dit l’évaluation du travail

…qui reste à faire.

…qu’il reste à faire.

Le temps

…qui nous reste à vivre.

…qu’il nous reste à vivre.

Comment: Qui vivra verra !

Comment: Voir aussi: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9029/ce-qui-se-passe-ou-ce-quil-se-passe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut dire les deux ! Cela se voit en séparant les deux propositions. Le verbe *rester* peut se construire personnellement ou impersonnellement. Le sens est le même.

> Du travail reste à faire. C'est le travail qui reste à faire.
> Il reste du travail à faire. C'est le travail qu'il reste à faire.

Si l'on précise qui doit faire le travail par un complément d'objet indirect, je crois que la tournure personnelle est vieillie. Mais je ne la considérerais pas comme incorrecte en français du début du 21<sup>e</sup> siècle, au moins si le COI est un pronom.

> Du travail leur reste à faire. C'est le travail qui leur reste à faire.
> Il leur reste du travail à faire. C'est le travail qu'il leur reste à faire.

> <sup>?</sup>Du travail reste à faire aux ouvriers. <sup>?</sup>C'est le travail qui reste à faire aux ouvriers.
> Il reste aux ouvriers du travail à faire. C'est le travail qu'il reste à faire aux ouvriers.